# jprofiler enabling CPU data startup

Tags: java, jprofiler

The accompanying help in JProfiler 7.2.2 states:
**"Unless "Record CPU data on startup" has been selected in the Startup section of the profiling settings dialog, data acquisition has to be started manually by clicking..."**

I don't have a "Startup" section in the profile settings dialog, much less a "Record CPU data on startup" checkbox.
Can anyone help with this?
I need CPU profiling turned on at startup in order to find the performance bottlenecks in my java 1.5 console app.

Answer (score 1):

See screen shot below, this dialog is shown when you start a profiling session.

[image]